# Como passar valor variável javascript para php?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Como posso passar para uma variável *php* o valor de um select, sempre que for selecionada uma opção diferente.

Tentei conforme abaixo, porém me retorna *[object HTMLSelectElement]*

```
$("select#tipo_documento").change(function (event) {

            var tipo_documento = document.getElementById('tipo_documento').value;
})

<?php
                $tipo_documento = "<script>"

         . "document.write(tipo_documento)"

         . "</script>";
            ?>
```

Comment: Tem mais de uma centena de perguntas sobre isso no site, fica a sugestão de pesquisar pra ver qual delas é mais parecida com o que você quer: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=vari%C3%A1vel+javascript+php

Answer (score 3):

Você está misturando códigos de FRONTEND (JavaScript) com códigos de BACKEND (PHP).

É possível passar o valor da variável do JavaScript `tipo_documento`  via `Ajax` para um arquivo `PHP`.

```
$("select#tipo_documento").change(function (event) {
      var tipo_documento = document.getElementById('tipo_documento').value;
      var req = this.createXMLHTTPObject();
      if (!req) return;
      var url = 'http://www.seu_site.com.br/seu_php.php?tipo_documento = ' . tipo_documento;
      req.open('GET',url,true);
      req.onreadystatechange = function () {          
        if (req.readyState != 4) {
            return;
        }
        if (req.status != 200 && req.status != 304) {
            alert('HTTP error ' + req.status);
            return;
        }


        alert('ok');
    }
    if (req.readyState == 4) return;
    req.send();


});
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu támbem passei por essa dúvida e depois de um bom tempo pensando achei uma solução extremamente simples de **passar uma variável de js ou HTML para PHP.**

Eu básicamente criei um **formulário** que quando o input (type="submit") enviaria uma variável do html/js para o php ... que pode ser usada na própria página ou até em outra página. outro método também pode ser usado... você pode **definir um cookie** em php de nome a sua escolha para que seja enviado ... no caso você usaria o código:

```
setcookie('nome do cookie', '<script>document.write(varivel);</script>' , time()+(30*24*3600));
```

Answer (score -2):

Use um elemento de texto hide com id único. Ou abre e fecha a tag PHP com echo no valor. Mas tem que levar em conta a ordem de criação do HTML no browser.